# 8051 Program gives correct answer but is not stopping in edSim8051

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051, edsim51

```
MOV 30H,#03H
MOV 31H,#03H
MOV 32H,#01H
MOV 33H,#04H
CLR C
MOV R0,#30H
MOV R2,#03H
MOV A,@R0
MOV 50H,A
UP: INC R0
MOV A,@R0
CJNE A,50H,DN
SJMP NEXT
DN: JC NEXT
MOV 50H,A
NEXT: DJNZ R2,UP
INC R0
MOV A,50H
MOV @R0,A
END
```

This is the 8051 code that keeps on running and does not stop

Comment: You are missing a `RET` or whatever edsim51 expects at the end. The `END` presumably only signals the end of the source file.

Comment: Use code formatting (select your code and hit control-k or use the menu), not double-spacing.

Comment: @Jester I tried that too...first I used RET alone and then RET followed by END but it is still going in a loop..i.e., it keeps running though the answer is correct

Comment: Any 8051 program runs forever in real life. (Having said that, if it does not switch off the power by some means.) -- So you need to find out what to tell your simulator to stop the simulation. It might be a special opcode, or a jump to a special location, or... What does the documentation say?